# /dev/sdc1 not showing under /dev/sdc for my pendrive

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, gparted, fdisk

I am trying to connect 16 DB kingston data traveller to my Ubuntu machine. This pendrive is not being detected in other machines. Thats why I tried to check it. When I issue a `lsblk` command, I am getting the below output.
[image]

Its showing /dev/sdc only/ /dev/sdc1 is not there. I think the partition is missing. I tried to format it using GParted, but the format option is disabled for this drive.

Is it hardware issue or something which can be corrected?

`lsblk -f` shows the following output.

[image]

`sudo blkid -c /dev/null` is showing as below.

[image]

I have tried to create new partition using fdisk also.
But its giving me read only error.

[image]

Comment: Could you show what `lsblk -f` and `sudo blkid -c /dev/null` list for sdc?

Comment: Try creating a partition for it with fdisk?

Comment: @user1686, I have added the results for the commands that you mentioned. Please check.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Reasons are listed on our sister site: [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: Ok @KamilMaciorowski. Will follow from now onwards. Thanks for guidance.

Comment: @davidgo I tried to create partition. But when I use fdisk /dev/sdc, I am getting permission error. Added the screenshot.

Comment: Please read the error message again: It’s not about permissions at all. Also, get a new flash drive, this one is done.